# Multiple select exists in a single statement

Tags: postgresql, select, multiple-columns, exists

I have the following piece of code:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS s CASCADE;  

CREATE SCHEMA s;

CREATE TABLE s.t1 (
    id1 BigInt,
    id2 BigInt,
    CONSTRAINT "pk1" PRIMARY KEY (id1)
)   
WITH(OIDS=FALSE);


INSERT INTO s.t1 (id1, id2) VALUES (2, 22);
INSERT INTO s.t1 (id1, id2) VALUES (3, 22);
INSERT INTO s.t1 (id1, id2) VALUES (4, 24);


SELECT EXISTS (SELECT TRUE FROM s.t1 t1 WHERE t1.id1 = 2,  
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT TRUE FROM s.t1 t1 WHERE t1.id2 = 22);
```

Is there a way to check for multiple conditions in a single statement.

I am looking for the values in two separate columns.
The answer I was looking for is something like this:

```
 bool | bool 
------+------
 t    | t
(1 row)
```

I got the solution:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT TRUE FROM s.t1 t1 WHERE t1.id1 = 6), 
EXISTS(SELECT TRUE FROM s.t1 t1 WHERE t1.id2 = 22);
```

Output:

```
 exists | exists 
 --------+--------
  f      | t
 (1 row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT max(x.t2) as t2,
       max(x.t22) as t22
FROM ((SELECT t1.id1 as t2, null as t22 FROM s.t1 t1 WHERE t1.id1 = 2)
        UNION
      (SELECT null as t2, t1.id2 as t22 FROM s.t1 t1 WHERE t1.id2 = 22)) as x;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/30a9e/10/0)

Comment: This gives me a single column. The idea is to have multiple such conditions and get the result in one query.

Comment: My bad, I just edited my answer
But now, I'm not sure about what are you trying to do

Comment: If you want to retrieve the two column data, you should probably use a `UNION` between your subqueries.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I got the solution based on your answer.

Answer (score 2):

EXISTS yields a Boolean value, which you can use directly:

---

```
SELECT
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM s.t1 x1  
        WHERE x1.id1 = 2)       AS ex1
  , EXISTS (SELECT * FROM s.t1 x2
        WHERE x2.id2 = 22)      AS ex2
        ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max( case when id1=2 then 'EXISTS' ELSE 'DOESN''T EXISTS' end) id1_2,
       max( case when id2=22 then 'EXISTS' ELSE 'DOESN''T EXISTS' end) id2_22,
       max( case when id2=33 then 'EXISTS' ELSE 'DOESN''T EXISTS' end) id2_33
FROM s.t1
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/85c47/11

```
|  id1_2 | id2_22 |         id2_33 |
|--------|--------|----------------|
| EXISTS | EXISTS | DOESN'T EXISTS |
```